# ASP MVC Authorize all actions except a few

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller and I would like to require Authorization for all actions by default except a couple. So in the example below all actions should require authentication except the Index. I don't want to decorate every action with the Authorize, I just want to override the default authorization in certain circumstances probably with a custom filter such as NotAuthorize.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    [NotAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // This one wont
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        // This action will require authorization
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Ok, this is what I did. If there is a better way let me know.

```
public class NotAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
    // Does nothing, just used for decoration
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Check if this action has NotAuthorizeAttribute
        object[] attributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true);
        if (attributes.Any(a => a is NotAuthorizeAttribute)) return;

        // Must login
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think MVC4 copied you and now we have [AllowAnonymous]

Comment: Still helpful to know when creating custom validation functionality in custom controllers :)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver, as you can see there are two pieces to this code. First is the piece which is covered by the `AllowAnonymous` and the second is not covered by the `AllowAnonymous`. I mean the second `if` clause - it checks whether or not a user is authenticated. Now if I want to avoid typing `Authorize` all the time, then I need it. Do we have something similar in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 33):

What about `[AllowAnonymous]` ??

Comment: This was created later, but is now the correct answer.

Comment: Ok. There is the `AllowAnonymous` attribute. But what should I do if I want all the other places to require authorization by default? I mean all the other controllers and actions. How can I avoid typing explicitly all the time that an authorization is required for my controller actions?

Answer (score 10):

MVC4 has a new attribute exactly meant for this `[AllowAnonymous]` (as pointed out by Enrico)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
```

Read all about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

Comment: Ok. There is the `AllowAnonymous` attribute. But what should I do if I want all the other places to require authorization by default? I mean all the other controllers and actions. How can I avoid typing explicitly all the time that an authorization is required for my controller actions?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha in your Startup.cs file or any equivalent of function `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` just add :
`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers()
                                                   .RequireAuthorization()
                                                   .RequireAuthorization([....AnyOtherDefaultAuthentYouNeed..]));`

Answer (score 6):

Here's what I would do, similar to Craig's answer with a couple of changes:

1) Create an ordinary attribute deriving from System.Attribute (no need to derive from FilterAttribute since you aren't going to be using anything FilterAttribute provides).

Maybe create a class hierarchy of attributes so you can test based on the hierarchy, e.g.

```
Attribute
    AuthorizationAttribute
         AuthorizationNotRequiredAttribute
         AuthorizationAdminUserRequiredAttribute
             AuthorizationSuperUserRequiredAttribute
```

2) In your BaseController override the `OnAuthorization` method rather than the `OnActionExecuting` method:

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var authorizationAttributes = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<AuthorizationAttribute>();
    bool accountRequired = !authorizationAttributes.Any(aa => aa is AuthorizationNotRequiredAttribute);
```

I like the approach of being secure by default: even if you forget to put an attribute on the Action it will at least require a user to be logged in.

Comment: if i override OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext), filterContext has no ActionDescriptor property, so i have no idea how to find the custom attributes from filterContext?

Comment: Can you confirm this is ASP.NET MVC 2?  There's definitely an ActionDescriptor there in V2.

Comment: installed mvc 2 and the code is running, i get inside my onAuthorisation overload, check for my attribute and if its found then return.

it then still redirects to the login page after i return out of the onAuth method?

EDIT : nvm its because i still had the authorise attribute on my controlelr

Answer (score 6):

Use a custom filter as described in [Securing your ASP.NET MVC 3 Application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx).

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, Stack Overflow answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time).

Answer (score 5):

Mark the controller with [Authorize]

[Authorize]
public class YourController : ApiController

Mark actions you want public with :

[AllowAnonymous]

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party, but I ended up creating a Controller-level auth attribute and an Action-level auth attribute and just skipping over the Controller auth if the Action had its own Auth attribute.  See code here:

https://gist.github.com/948822