# Need to login to view video asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, authentication

I am a beginner with C# and Asp.net. I will try to explain this as best I can. I work at a university that allows access to a lot of different sites, payroll, hr, databases...etc. through a central authentication unit. You login on a subdomain of the site and based on your account, you have access to whatever is allowed to you.

I am working with a small department that wants a video on their website, but they want employees to have to login first, in order to see that video.

Can anyone recommend on how to achieve this, I am kind of dead in the water here. Any help is appreciated. Is there a way I can use asp.net to check if they are logged in? Or is this beyond my hands.

Comment: Determine how an employee is identified compared to other types of users (probably a role called 'employee') and create an authorization requirement.

Comment: Authorize attribute on actions and check for roles, roles can be stored in database for each user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780715/asp-net-mvc-roles-authorization

Answer (score 2):

To deny access to a specific page say: video.aspx, you can use location element in your web.config. This will always deny access to users who are not logged in and will redirect them to your default login page configured.

```
<configuration>
   <location path="root/video.aspx"> //Specify your correct Path to Video Page
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

However, if you want authentication on whole of a section of website, which will be a separate folder in VisualStudion, make sure in the  root of this separate folder, you place a web.config with below entry. Only thing that your code to validate user in login page will be using the Central authentication standards.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

You can refer this URL for a very basic startup: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET