# Read-only user permissions in MVC3 application with minimum changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, filter, readonly

I've got a task of creating a read-only user for our ASP.Net MVC3 application. I.e. they can login, view all the data, but can not update any data.

I have read a lot of authentication articles/frameworks, like this one: [Implement secure ASP.NET MVC applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC3-applications), or [Fluent Security Configuration](http://www.marius-schulz.net/blog/securing-an-aspnet-mvc-application-using-fluentsecurity), or [Creating Action Filters in ASP.Net MVC](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18959/Creating-Custom-Action-Filters-in-ASPNET-MVC.htm) (and a few other, I have lost links to already).

The problem with most of the approaches that they require drastic changes to the domain/application. And I have only **one day** to implement the feature.

We have about a hundred of controllers with on average of 4 actions per controller (mostly CRUD operations), and going through every single one of them is out of the question. Also it would be easy to forget to put attributes on the the new code - introducing bugs.

So far I have came up with global filter that denies all POST-based actions and controller actions called "Create" for read-only user:

```
public class ReadOnlyFilter : IActionFilter 
{

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var currentUser = HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (currentUser == null || !currentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return; // user is not logged in yet


        if (!currentUser.IsInRole("Readonly")) 
            return; // user is not read-only. Nothing to see here, move on!

        // Presume User is read-only from now on.


        // if action is of type post - deny
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/ReadOnlyAccess");
        }

        // if action is "Create" - deny access
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "Create")
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/ReadOnlyAccess");
        }

        // if action is edit - check if Details action exits -> redirect to it.
        //TODO get this done ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        return;
    }


    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // blah! have to have this here for IActionFilter
    }
}
```

Next thing I plan to create attribute [AllowReadOnlyUser] for post actions, like changing the password/email, and in the filter allow that action to go through.

I wonder if there are better ways to do this kind of thing?

*Update*: The application is not for public consumption. It is used in corporate world to track people, assets and other boring data.

**Update 2**: I've seems to be finished with this task. Done it as a controller, as started. Full code and some explanation you [can see in my blog](http://tech.trailmax.info/2012/09/read-only-user-in-mvc3-with-minimal-changes/).

Comment: This will allow posts for not logged in users. Also I'm not sure "POST" is guaranteed to be uppercase.

Comment: Our application is used only by logged in users. No controllers apart from LoginController are available to the world. So that's fine. Fair point about the POST. I'll get it fixed - thanks!

Comment: I recently had to convert an older asp.net webforms app to read only mode in very little time. My solution was to use javascript/jquery to disable all input controls and non-navigation hyperlinks, and strip all click/submit function code to prevent postbacks.

Comment: @asawyer Yeah, that will work. Until you get a user who knows how to use debug tools in browser and some jquery.

Comment: @trailmax I won't deny that's possible, but I was unable to go back in and repair the page to the point it was able to post successfully even with an intimate knowledge of the application and web forms.  Plus my app was internal only and was just for state auditors who were unlikely to attempt something like that. I had it done in just a few hours though, which is why I suggested it. If you'd like I can post the script for you to look at and test.

Comment: @asawyer Yeah, that sounds interesting. Do you mind posting as an answer? so you get your share of upvotes -)

Comment: @trailmax It's posted. Let me know if you manage to repair and post a form after it's running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute for your purpose. Create a class that derives from AuthorizeAttribute and override the methods AuthorizeCore and HandleUnauthorizedRequest. In AuthorizeCore you determine if a user is allowed to execute an action, in HandleUnauthorizedRequest you determine what to display if he isn't allowed (for instance, show a "NotAllowed"-View).

After creating your custom authorization attribute, you have to add the attribute to all controller actions that should be protected by your custom authorization. For instance, all POST-methods. But if there is a POST-method that should be allowed for all users, you just don't add the attribute to that controller action.

Comment: We have looked at this option before and had to reject it. We have a LOT of controllers and littering [ReadOnly] attribute around is not the best option and is bug-magnet for new controllers.

Comment: you could still use AuthorizeAttribute on a controller level or even derive your controllers from a custom controller with the attribute in place. If a method has its own AuthorizeAttribute, don't do anything on controller level. You'd have to override the OnAuthorization method to check for method level attributes. Would still mean to modify all your controllers, though. But i'm not sure if generically catching methods by their name and request type is a good idea, as it relies on conventions applied on an organizational level (we only use "Create" for create methods) just as much.

Comment: +1. Now that looks like a much better idea. I'll have a look on that.

Comment: here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780436/asp-mvc-authorize-all-actions-except-a-few . One of the (later) answers also contains code for controller level/method level authorization, see here: https://gist.github.com/948822

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to tweak this a bit, and before anyone tells me I am 100% aware that this is a terrible hack. But it's also pretty effective and very quickly implemented which was the overriding concern at the time.  You'll want to run this through an obsficator of course.

There is also some update panel stuff in there that would have to be removed, or changed to jQuery ajax response end hooks or something like that if needed.

Oh and there is this to control running it for read only users only:

```
if (isReadonly && !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("ReadonlyScriptController"))
{
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
  "ReadonlyScriptController", "<script>RunReadonlyScript();</script>");
}
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/ClientScripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RunReadonlyScript() {
        //Extend jquery selections to add some new functionality
        //namely, the ability to select elements based on the
        //text of the element.
        $.expr[':'].textEquals = function (a, i, m) {
            var match = $(a).text().match("^" + m[3] + "$");
            return match && match.length > 0;
        };
        //this function does all the readonly work
        var disableStuff = function () {

            //select all controls that accept input, save changes, open a popup, or change form state
            // ** customize this with your own elements **
            $('button, input:not(:hidden), textarea, select,
              a:textEquals("Clear Selection"), 
              a:textEquals("Add Message"), 
              a:textEquals("CCC EVAL"),
              a[id$="availLink"], 
              a[id$="lbtnDelete"], 
              a[id$="lbtnEdit"]')
                //disable input controls
                .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
                //remove onclick javascript
                .removeAttr('onclick')
                //remove all bound click events
                .unbind("click")
                //add a new click event that does nothing
                //this stops <a> links from working
                .click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    return false;
                });

            //zap some images with click events that we don't want enabled
            $('img[id$="imgCalendar1"], img[id$="imgDelete"]').hide();
        }
        //if we are loading the home page, don't disable things
        //or the user won't be able to use the search controls
        var urlParts = document.URL.split('/');
        var last2 = urlParts[urlParts.length - 2] + '/' + urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
        if (last2 !== 'home/view') {
            //disable everything initially
            disableStuff();
            //setup a timer to re-disable everything once per second
            //some tab panels need this to stay disabled
            setInterval(disableStuff, 1000);
            //some pages re-enable controls after update panels complete
            //make sure to keep them disabled!
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(disableStuff);
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(disableStuff);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, it is useful. I'm using this as an addition to what I already have on the server-side: If view provides input elements and they are not disabled on the server for some reason, your jquery kicks-in. Once I finish, I'll do a blog-post on the topic and put a link in question.

Comment: Also, I have just played with Chrome console and did manage to submit the form via script: `$('button, input:not(:hidden), textarea, select').removeAttr("disabled"); $("#Comment").val("Hello, i'm from jquery console");$("form").submit();`   So this is a nice addition to UI experience and must be backed up by server side measures (if this feature is critical).

Comment: @trailmax I suppose a MVC is easier to post too then trying to get a webform postback working again. I never actually tried it on MVC. I've booked marked this question though, and in case I need this for any of my newer app!